Un cantante que *lo* hemos coronado como ... - why 'lo'?
What is the function of 'lo' in this line from the great Héctor Lavoe song? It seems to me that the sentence would work without it and I can't figure out what its function is.
What would be the best literal/word for word translation? Thanks!

Un cantante que lo hemos coronado como el rey de la puntualidad


The singer, or the song, may be great, but the grammar is not. That "lo" is grammatically wrong because it duplicates the direct object, a function that is already fulfilled by the relative pronoun "que".

Literal word-for-word translation is meaningless. What's the point?

The phrase:

Un cantante que lo hemos coronado como el rey de la puntualidad

would be far better expressed as follows:

Un cantante (al) que hemos coronado como el rey de la puntualidad

Un cantante a quien hemos coronado como el rey de la puntualidad

Un cantante al cual hemos coronado como el rey de la puntualidad


The coexistence of "que" and "lo", both of which act as direct objects, renders "lo" redundant (and incorrect in formal language).
In colloquial Spanish, we can find that "lo", which is known as pleonastic or resumptive, as can be read here.

"Lo" se usa de forma inconsciente aun cuando no se debería usar, ya que se puede usar otras formas más acordes y formales al lenguaje castellano, es como una palabra de relleno aun cuando no es necesario usarla.
